# swift: Alphabetiz data being parsed from a JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, sorting, swift2

I wrote my own function in Swift2 to parse a JSON. Once the JSON is parsed, a list of data that was pulled from the JSON is displayed in a `tableView` on my app. I am trying to figure out how to display this data in alphabetical order. I think this needs to happen somewhere before the append method I call in the function. I would imagine this needs to be a `sort` function but I have not been able to figure out the correct sort function in Swift2 that will execute this properly. Any help I can get is appreciated!
Here is my parseJSON function:

```
 func parseJSON(){
    do{
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/580d0ccce4b0bcac9f837fbe")!)

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

            let mifiName2 = anItem["name"] as! String
            let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int

            let newName = Name(mifiName: mifiName2, mifiId: mifiId)
            nameOfMifi.append(newName)
            //print("Name: \(newName)")

        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never** load data from a server with the synchronous method `NSData(contentsOfURL:` and `MutableContainers` is useless in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `sort` your array after all the object is `append` in `Array` means after the `for` loop.

```
for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

    let mifiName2 = anItem["name"] as! String
    let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int

    let newName = Name(mifiName: mifiName2, mifiId: mifiId)
    nameOfMifi.append(newName)
    //print("Name: \(newName)")
}

//Now you need to sort your array on the basis of name like this
nameOfMifi.sortInPlace { $0.mifiName < $1.mifiName }
```

**Edit:** As @vadian suggested do not use `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` because it will block your UI, so batter to use `NSURLSession` like this.

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/580d0ccce4b0bcac9f837fbe")!
var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        return
    }

    if let jsonResult = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

        for anItem in jsonResult {

            let mifiName2 = anItem["name"] as! String
            let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int

            let newName = Name(mifiName: mifiName2, mifiId: mifiId)
            nameOfMifi.append(newName)
            //print("Name: \(newName)")
        }
        //Now you need to sort your array on the basis of name like this
        nameOfMifi.sortInPlace { $0.mifiName < $1.mifiName } 

        //Now reload tableView on main thread.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: where does the method to reload the tableView go? I tried putting it in my viewDidLoad() and I keep getting the error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'" on the world self

Comment: @user7077886 Check the edited answer, Also here `self.tableView` is your tableView outlet that you have created, you need to change it with you tableView Outlet name.

Comment: Thank you so much! And I had no idea I should be using NSURLSessions so thank you for explaining that as well!

Comment: @user7077886 Welcome mate :)